# LINQ- Combine Multiple List<T> and order by a value (.Net 3.5)

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics

I'm trying to combine a number of `List<T> where T:IGetTime` (i.e `T` will always have method `getTime()`).

Then I'm trying order the items by the `DateTime` that `getTime()` returns.

My LINQ looks like this:

```
public static List<T> Combine(List<T> one, List<T> two, List<T> three)
    {
        var result = from IGetTime item in one
                     from IGetTime item2 in two
                     from IGetTime item3 in three
                     select new{ item, item2, item3 };

        return result.ToList();
    }
```

I've yet to add an `orderby`. Which should look somthing like this:

```
var thestream = from T item in this
                orderby item.getTime() descending
                select item;
```

Is there anyway to both combine and order the final list????

Thanks in advance,

Roberto

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You've got three lists here - what *exactly* are you trying to order by?

Your cast is incorrect too - the result will be an `IEnumerable<X>` where `X` is an anonymous type with three `T`s in.

If the idea is really to *concatenate* the three lists and then sort, you want:

```
return one.Concat(two)
          .Concat(three)
          .OrderByDescending(x => x.GetTime())
          .ToList();
```

Comment: Does C# know that x will have a GetTime method (or cast it toa IGetTime) simply due to a where T: IGetTime?  If not the Lambda needs adjustment to x => ((IGetTime)x).GetTime()

Comment: C~ does know. T is explicitly declated inthe clas decleration: public class TimeStream<T> : List<T> where T : IGetTime

Comment: Wow it does work without the cast, can't help shake the feeling that this is taking C# magix pixie dust a little too far.

Comment: @Roberto:  There is still magic happening, it is silently casting x to IGetTime even though the type of T is something else.  Its doing this by checking each interface in the restriction list looking for a matching signature of GetTime().

Comment: @AnthonyWJones: Much of the benefit of generics is to replace run-time casting with compile-time type checking.  The types are all there, specified by the programmer.  The compiler doesn't have to work too hard to check that these instances have that method.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
public static List<T> Combine<T, TKey>
(
  Func<T, TKey> orderingFunction,
  params IEnumerable<T>[] theParams
)
  where TKey : IComparable
{
  return theParams
    .SelectMany(x => x)
    .OrderBy(orderingFunction)
    .ToList();
}
```

Here's some test code:

```
    public static void Test1()
    {
        List<int> a = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
        List<int> b = new List<int>() { 3, 2, 1 };
        List<int> c = CombineLists.Combine(i => i, a, b);
        c.ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine(i));
    }
```

Here's the story:

```
public static List<T> Combine<T, TKey>
(
  Func<T, TKey> orderingFunction,
  params IEnumerable<T>[] theParams
)
  where TKey : IComparable
```

This signature declares a method that takes two type parameters, some ordering function and a bunch of collections.  Notice that the types T and TKey are not specified explicitly in the test call.  The compiler has a little puzzle to figure out what these types are.  First it inspects the IEnumerables that it has been given (a and b) and discovers they are IEnumerable of int.  Aha, T must be int.  Then it inspects the ordering function and sees that it returns the same type that it is passed.  Aha, TKey must be int.

The *where* is kind of funny.  OrderBy should check (at compile time) that TKey is IComparable.  It only checks at runtime, so we get to do the compile time check in our code.

[params](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx) takes as many parameters as you like and refers to them be creating an array.  Who wants to be limited to three lists?

```
        return theParams
            .SelectMany(x => x)
            .OrderBy(orderingFunction)
            .ToList();
```

[SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx) unpacks a collection of collections.  This is a way to flatten one level of hierarchy.
[OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx) takes some function that projects each element to an orderable value, and orders the elements according to those values.
[ToList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) enumerates the query and returns the list.  No surprises there.